# Error: Attribute v-for not allowed on element tr at this point

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Error: Attribute v-for not allowed on element tr at this point.

From line 50, column 29; to line 51, column 50

↩                        ↩   
 Attribute v-for not allowed on element tbody at this point.

From line 75, column 25; to line 76, column 44

↩                ↩

Attributes for element tbody:
Global attributes
My code is:

```
`

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <!-- This page will diplay after manager sign up -->
        <title>Admins main page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheets/admins.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f0e67e1ed8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src = "javascripts/admins.js" defer></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <!--This is background color that used on each page-->
    <body class = "background-color-page" onload = "getUsersinformation();getClubsinformation()">
        <!--All of head functions such as logo and function button should on the header-->
       <header class = "header_bottom">
            <!--Set a absolute white color the display on the inside ofn header -->
            <div class = "div_background_color">
                <!--This navgation bar include almost main function-->
                <!--Club Members Notifactions totally three functions on nav bar-->
                <nav>
                    <ul class = "ul-navbar">
                        <!--The manager will go to the clubs if touch the club text-->
                        <li class = "navbar-li"><a class = "navbar-li-link" href="club.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>Club</a></li>
                        <!--The manager will go to the managers if touch the memebers text-->
                        <li class = "navbar-li"><a class = "navbar-li-link" href="members.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Members</a></li>
                        <!--The manager will go to the notifications if touch the notifactions text-->
                        <li class = "navbar-li"><a class = "navbar-li-link" href="notifications.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>Notifactions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
       </header>

            <div class = "div-style-left" id = "usertable">
                <section class = "section-border">
                    <h3><span class = "title-memebers">
                            Members
                    </span>
                    </h3>
                </section>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class = "distance_general">Users name</th>
                            <th class = "distance_general">Type</th>
                            <th class = "distance_general">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >
                        <tr v-for = "i in actors">
                            <td class = "distance_general">{{ i.user_name }}</td>
                            <td class = "distance_general">{{ i.user_type }}</td>
                            <td class = "distance_general"><button type="button" v-bind:value="i.user_id" @click="deletUser(i.user_id)"> Delete </button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
       <!--Div on right-->
        <div class = "div-style-left" id = "clubtable">
            <section class = "section-border">
                <h3><span class = "title-memebers">
                        Clubs
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <!-- <button class = "button-place" type = "button" onclick="document.location = 'club.html'">Manage</button> -->
            </section>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class = "distance_general">Club name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody v-for = "i in clubs">
                <tr>
                    <td class = "distance_general">{{ i.club_name }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class = "div-style-left">
            <aside>
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class = "title-memebers">Signup new admin</legend>
                        <label for="Usersname" class = "label_type">Student Name</label>
                        <input id = "Usersname" class = "input_type" type = "text" placeholder="Student name">
                        <button type = "button" class = "button_type" onclick="addadmin()">Add</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
`
```

This is my js code

```
    // For users
var usersif = new Vue({
    el: "#usertable",
    data: {
    actors: []

    },
    methods:{

        deletUser(currValue) {

            console.log("current click button: " + currValue);

            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    alert("Delete successfully");
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", "/deletUser", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
                newadminname: currValue
            }));

        }
    }
});
// For clubs
var clubif = new Vue({
    el: "#clubtable",
    data: {
    clubs: []
    }
});
// collect the users information to usersif array
function getUsersinformation() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                usersif.actors = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              }
          };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/getUsersinformation", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
// collect the clubs information to usersif array
function getClubsinformation() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                var responseData = JSON.parse(this.response);
                console.log(this.responseText);
                clubif.clubs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              }
          };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/getClubsinformation", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

// collect input information about new admin
function addadmin() {

    let usersname = document.getElementById("Usersname").value;

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // document.getElementById("output").innerText = this.responseText;
        }
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 505) {
            alert("no manager or admin!!");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/addadmin", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
        newadminname: usersname
    }));

}
```

Do I need to fix this error? How do I fix it if I need to?
Thank you all.

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong code. There is no `v-for` or `<tbody>` element anywhere in the code you've shown.  It's not even a Vue app as far as I can tell.

Comment: sorry gus, my bad.

Comment: @Jaromanda X I'm sorry about the space, because I have some bad code writing habits. As for why I use v-for, it is because I am trying to use vue.js to import the contents of the database, and v-for can play a similar role in this for loop.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because he still reported an error after repeated checking with no space. For the use of the vue version, the information provided by our school shows that it is Vue.js v2.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my comments, wasn't that convinced it was the issue anyway :p

Comment: your code doesn't produce that error for me, are there no other errors in the console? does the error occur on page load or some other time?

Comment: I consulted a few people, and they said it wasn't a mistake

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you isolated the problem to a small example instead of pasting hundreds of lines of code for us to sort through.